# MariaDB Query works and MYSQL does not

Tags: mysql, mariadb, find-in-set

I have two web sites with identical database tables.  If the following query is run on the site using 10.2.25-MariaDB-log it works, but if run on the site using MYSQL 5.6.45 it does not. Here is the query:

```
SELECT masterpoints_total, FIND_IN_SET( masterpoints_total, 
( SELECT   GROUP_CONCAT( masterpoints_total ORDER BY masterpoints_total
DESC ) FROM `members` ) ) AS rank FROM members WHERE number = "N433975"`
```

On the MYSQL Maria site the results are 1033(masterpoints_total) and 630(rank) while on the MYSQL site the results are 1033 and 0. Zero is not correct.

How can I fix the MYSQL site to properly show the rank?

Thanks.

Comment: The way you use `find_in_set()` and `group_concat()` looks akward. Please share sample data and expected results, as well as an explanation of what you are trying to accomplish so we can suggest a solution.

Comment: 'The result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the group_concat_max_len system variable, which has a default value of 1024. ' - any chance these differ?https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: The table (relevant columns) looks like this:

masterpoints_total          number
0                                       1234567
20,000                              P765432
1033                                 N433975
50                                     4539721
50                                     8764321

Comment: The group_concat_max_len is set to 1024, so that may be the problem.  There are over 3000 rows in the table. This is on a shared server and I am not sure I can change the max_len.  I'll check.

Comment: Yes, changing the max length fixed the issue.  Thanks.

I think you have to answer for me to accept the answer.